# MySQL or SQLITE to store who voted

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, rating

I want to create a rating system (Ajax) with PHP for some images. Only registered users will be able to vote so i am going to store their id.

My question is should i create a table in MySQL where i will store the user id and photo id for all the images/ratings or should i write a script which will create a seperate SQLite file/database for EACH image where it will store the users' ids who voted.

I am going to use this table **only** to check if the user voted for this image or not. Total votes and score will be stored in another MySQL table.

Which would be faster?

```
MySQL (containing users' ids who voted from ALL the images)

image_id  |  user_id
---------------------
   114    |     12
   114    |     24
   114    |     53
   114    |     1
```

or

```
1 SQLite file foreach image rating

image_114.sqlite

user_id
-------
  12
  24
  53
  1
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use the structure from your first example, but without a hard dependency on MySQL, so SQlite could still be used. Here is why:

- I consider your second example abuse of a database. Assume, you want to show a page containing the highest ratest images .. how would you do so with the second approach?
- The first approach seems quite fine to me, but since the structure is so trivial, why include a dependency on MySQL? Being able to run on "just about every" SQL makes the app a lot more portable

Comment: Total score and total votes will be stored in another table (images' table) so i can sort them by selecting total_score/total_votes as a result sorting is not a problem. Each time a user rates the image those two fields' values will be increased

Comment: If you already have a central database, I strongly recommend you put the single votes there also